# Add nested object properties to the main object

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I have a response from an api call which is an array of Objects. I want to modify every object by removing the nested object 'company' and nested it directly to the main object.
Is there a way to do that with a fast way ?

```
{
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "hostname": "test.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "city": "São Paulo",
    "region": "São Paulo",
    "country": "Brazil",
    "loc": "-33.5375,-36.31",
    "org": "AS16509 Amazon.com, Inc.",
    "postal": "01000-000",
    "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "company": {
      "name": "Amazon Data Services Brazil",
      "domain": "amazon.com",
      "type": "hosting"
    },
    "countryCode": "BR"
}
```

I want to change the json to this

```
{
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "hostname": "test.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "city": "São Paulo",
    "region": "São Paulo",
    "country": "Brazil",
    "loc": "-33.5375,-36.31",
    "org": "AS16509 Amazon.com, Inc.",
    "postal": "01000-000",
    "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "name": "Amazon Data Services Brazil",
    "domain": "amazon.com",
    "type": "hosting"
    "countryCode": "BR"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function but I am checking if there's a faster method.

```
const formatObj = (obj) =>{
  obj.name = obj.company.name;
  obj.domain = obj.company.domain;
  obj.type = obj.company.type;
  delete obj.company
  return obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newList = listFromAPI.map((object) => {
delete object.company
return {...object};
});
```

here newList will have all the list of objects without company property

Answer (score 0):

Using [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) :

```js
const obj = {
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "hostname": "test.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "city": "São Paulo",
    "region": "São Paulo",
    "country": "Brazil",
    "loc": "-33.5375,-36.31",
    "org": "AS16509 Amazon.com, Inc.",
    "postal": "01000-000",
    "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
    "company": {
      "name": "Amazon Data Services Brazil",
      "domain": "amazon.com",
      "type": "hosting"
    },
    "countryCode": "BR"
}

const result = { ...obj, ...obj.company, company: void 0 }

console.log( result )
```